# Newsletter option of magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database, magento-enterprise

I would like send newsletter from Magento control panel.But that function not working. How can i send newsletter from Magento. How is it working? if you have any reference link send me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first create a template for a store. people subscribe to the newsletter of your store. then when done with the template, you go to the newsletter and in the list and from the dropdown click Newsletter Queue. then you select which store the newsletter is for, queue date start, etc. then just hit Save newsletter and it will be added to the queue. Note: you must have cron enabled to send newsletters.

Comment: you can add one in your cpanel/directadmin environment

Comment: yes, i am in cpanel cron job, then what is the next one..

Comment: here is my cron job, what can i do

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HDjOQ4s.png

Comment: you can make it run every 5 min. then command `/path/to/your/php -f /path/to/your/site/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: is it ok  http://i.imgur.com/vIJNkXK.png

Comment: what is the next one ?

Comment: lol I don't mean literally put /path/to/your/php, I mean find out where it is on your server (I can't tell you that because I can't look in your server), the same for the path to your site

Comment: yes, you are right,

Comment: could you pls guide dummy values of cpanel

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Wbx5QJt.png

Comment: you need to login to your server with SSH to find out where the PHP is located and what the path to your site is

Comment: Is this right  http://i.imgur.com/qLU5fZr.png

Comment: could be, just make sure to add a space between path to your php and the -f command

Comment: Is this ok now?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HYCWX8F.png